# Best choice for handling forms in React

Tags: reactjs, forms, state, formik

I need help understanding what is the best choice for forms in React. We will have multiple forms in our app. I'm thinking one of these three options:

1. Formik
2. One useState object that will store info from all fields, and one event handler.
3. Multiple states. For every input one state with its own handler.

Comment: https://react-hook-form.com/faqs#ReactHookFormFormikorReduxForm

Comment: I second @Moath 's suggestion. Formik gets laggy when there's a lot of input.

Comment: I suggest using `react-hook-form` to prevent extra rerenders like `formik`